# Does rails has a pagination gem/function as pagination in laravel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, laravel, pagination

Laravel has a [pagintaion](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination) function, it's very simple to generate pagination info.

```
$users = DB::table('users')->paginate(15);
```

Does rails has something like that?

Comment: You *could* Google for: 'rails pagination gem'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) for instance, with the following syntax:

```
User.page(7).per(50)
```

There is also [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)